# How do I announce an area-restricted feature without discouraging the rest of my visitors?

Tags: technical-writing, marketing, tone

I want to make an announcement to my users at my website about a new feature launch. However, in its first phase, this new feature has limited access - it will be supporting only one city for now, and later to some others.

My attempts so far feel like they'll be discouraging to all my visitors who *aren't* from those particular cities. How do I write enthusiastically about this, without most of my readers feeling like they're being left out?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We are not a discussion board. We require clear, answerable questions which have the potential to help others. As written, this is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us. If you'd like to post something you've written and ask "How do I improve it in a particular way?", that's something the community can help you with. Please take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to learn more.

Comment: This actually _does_ look to me like a very particular question - "I need to announce that we're only supporting one city, but I feel like I'm leaving other readers out." Possibly it could use a little tweaking, and an example sample would actually be helpful, but I like it :)

Comment: I've rewritten and I think the question stands nicely now. @learner, I hope I've kept your original intention!

Comment: A question: is the service _intended_ to spread more widely with time? Can you pitch this as a pilot phase which will expand, or are the people outside those few cities going to be left out indefinitely?

Comment: Thanks @standback for helping out and restructuring the question. That really makes sense. To your question; yes it is intended to spread with time.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it as an early report on your *beta launch*, or as a preview of your *forthcoming launch*.  Assuming that you're restricting it now so you can work the kinks out before spreading more widely, it helps to also talk about what you've learned -- we found and fixed this performance problem at scale, we discovered that this one part of our user interface was confusing and did such-and-such to fix it, this week we fixed this many user-reported bugs (average turnaround time N hours), and so on.

Along with conveying news about your feature, for a beta launch like this you want to convey that there is *forward motion* -- that people who have to wait are benefiting from this wait.  Assuming that the broader availability is in the foreseeable future, regular progress reports can also help you keep people interested -- this is the "update bulletin" model used by Kickstarter and similar services.